# Workflow status hangs in "starting" forever

Tags: workflow

WHy does de workflow hangs on 'starting' forever?

it wont start automatically, if i start it manually it'll work but wont fire the events ( in this case , my task created event) , this is happening to development enviroment from a time to now, in the production enviroment it works fine. The event log says  With event id 6763:

SafeControl load exception:Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c Exception: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPGroupMigrator' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.

but i dont know if this error has to do withthe workflow.

I hate it because im not able to debug my workflow.

running moss 2007,  the workflos is attached to a list. when i clic start workflow, im able to debug the workflow but it wont fire the next step ( event on task created ) .

please help

Answer (score 1):

This was possibly caused by an earlier hotfix.

Make sure you're running SP2 and then install the lastest CU for WSS and MOSS.